# Problem reading File using UTF-8 encoding in java

Tags: java, swing, io

when i read the entire XML file in JEditorPane all works fine except the BOM charatcer. I get a BOM charatcer (a dot) at start of file. If i remove the dot and save file it is saved as ANSI.In notepad++ it shows (ANSI as UTF-8) encoding for the same file. If i dont remove the dot XML parser fails to parse the document. Can u help me with this.???? thanks.

Comment: Which parser ? have you define the content-type on the JEditorPane ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XML file only contains ASCII characters it will be valid ASCII/ANSI as well as valid UTF8, so don't worry about Notepad++ recognizing the file as ANSI.

While you can use a BOM for UTF8, it is discouraged because it will break a lot of Unix programs and you really shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Continue use UTF-8 without BOM.
Try Editplus go to menu 
Document->File Encoding ->Change File Encoding 
then chose UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-D` option of the `java` command, set the system property `file.encoding`, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942282).

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

utf-8 does not use the BOM, so most programs don't expect it and fail to parse/handle it. As far as I know only some Microsoft programs insert it to detect the utf-8 encoding faster.

**Solution:**

- Remove the BOM, nobody needs it.
- Don't use buggy editors with non standard encoding. (=> my opinion)